# How do I prevent armature+animation from overriding physics in rigid body simulation?

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've been running into a problem where objects that are animated with armatures do not behave as I expect in a rigid body simulation. I put together an example to show the problem that I'm having.

In this example, I have two boxes stacked on top of each other with an arm made of two rectangular prisms coming out of the bottom one. At the end of this arm, there is a sphere. This system is sitting on the edge of a plane. Everything is its own object and I have also included empty axes where each joint will be in the rigid body simulation.

[image: The scene before adding an armature]

What I would like to do is create a rigid body simulation where the arm and top top box are controlled by an armature. I would like to extend the arm outward, and have the center of mass of the system change so that the two boxes and arm fall as a single unit off the edge of the plane. I figured the best place to start would be to add everything to a rigid body simulation. The plane is the only passive object, the rest are active. Each object has a mass of 1kg except for the sphere which has a mass of 10kg. I also used fixed rigid body constraints at each of the joints.

To get rid of some of the slop and bounciness in the system, I increased the steps per second and solver iterations in the rigid body world settings. When I ran the simulation, everything remained still as expected. Just as a sanity test for myself, I moved the sphere off off to the right a little ways and the system tipped over as expected. I put the sphere back where it belongs and started to add the armature.

[image: The Armature]
[image: Demonstration of Armature]

After adding the armature, I tested it out to make sure everything moved with the armature as expected, which it did. When I lowered the bones controlling the arms the two rectangular prisms lowered with them, and when I twisted the bone controlling the upper box, the box twisted with it. So, I added some keyframes for the bone rotation at the starting frame and with the lowered arm about a second into the animation. When I went to play it back, I found that the arm did not lower. This was the result:

[image: Animated option disabled result]

At this point I did not have the Animated option enabled for the rigid body physics, so I tried again with this enabled for every active object except for the sphere. This time, the arm lowered but the group of objects did not fall off the plane as I would have expected. Here's the result of that:

[image: Animated option enabled result]

How would I go about making a sort of robotic system made of various pieces like this that is controlled by an armature and also responds to rigid body physics? I would like the joints of the robot to be controlled by rotating bones in the armature. Also, if there is an approach other than using an armature for this, I would be open to trying that out instead.

I will try to add the .blend file and could make a video more clearly showing the problem if there is any confusion.

Edit: I am using Blender 2.82a

[image]